# mysqlで更新クエリの多いテーブルにカラム追加したらＤＢ負荷が高まりサイトが落ちました。

Tags: mysql

PHP+mysqlでwebサービス稼働中なのですが、更新クエリ（トランザクション）が多く発行されるテーブルに対し日中、ALTER TABLEでカラム1件を追加したところ、DB負荷が高まりサイトアクセスできなくなり、mysqlを再起動せざるを得ない状態となりました。

[漢のコンピュータ道氏のサイト](http://nippondanji.blogspot.jp/2009/05/alter-table.html)によりますと以下のように書かれてあり、これは負荷かかるだろうなと思いました。

> まず結論から言うと、なんとMySQLのALTER
>   TABLEはテーブルのデータを全てコピーし直すのである。なんて無駄なことを！？と思うかも知れないが、テーブル定義（スキーマ）の変更を動的に行うには、ストレージエンジンによるサポートが必要であり、動的なスキーマ変更をサポートしているストレージエンジンはまだ少ないのである。

みなさんはサービス稼働中のサイトにどのようにALTER TABLEを実行していますか？
サービスを止めたりしていますか？または深夜に行う等

■バージョン情報
バージョン：5.1.73
ストレージエンジン：INNODB

Answer (score 1):

バージョンは、 8.0.12~ になってしまいますが、 instant add column という機能が追加されたようです。

これは何かというと、 DDL 実行時に InnoDB は変更せず、 MySQL 8 から導入された（たしか） Data Dictionary のメタデータだけを更新することで、 ADD COLUMN 等、一部の DDL を一瞬で終わらせる仕組みの様子です。

```
-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-operations
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN c2 INT, ADD COLUMN c3 INT, ALGORITHM=INSTANT;
```

また、日本語の解説としては、以下のページを発見しています。

https://y-asaba.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/12/21/002811

---

また、 8 までいかなくても、 5.6 ぐらいから、 INPLACE の ADD COLUMN もできるようになっている様子です。これは、 add column をしている最中でも、参照や更新をできるようにするための仕組みの様子です。

なので、8 までいかないにせよ、 MySQL のバージョンをあげることで、解決可能な問題であるようだ、と思っています。